# cmpeqpd sometimes returns wrong values

Tags: assembly, floating-point, sse, avx, denormal-numbers

For some reason, sometimes in my program I see that

```
cmpeqpd xmm3,xmm0
```

where `xmm0 == {0x2cd000000000, 0x2cd000000000}`
and `xmm3 == {0x0, 0x2011d0800000000}`
happens to return `{0xffffffffffffffff, 0x0}` in xmm3, which is, well, wrong, since `(double)0x0` is not equal to `(double)0x2cd000000000`.

I've noticed that it happens only occasionally. I've recorded the execution of the program with rr so that to reproduce this consistently. Funnily enough, in a super reduced simple program I can't reproduce this issue anymore. I wonder, are there any hidden microarchitectural states that can change cmpeqpd (cmppd) behavior?

Just a note, I checked that upper 128bits in the corresponding ymm registers are zeroed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

0x2CD000000000 (or 0x00002CD000000000 to make it more obvious what the exponent is doing) is denormal. There is indeed a setting that would make a denormal compare equal to zero: the [DAZ flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54047415/do-denormal-flags-like-denormals-are-zero-daz-affect-comparisons-for-equality)

The DAZ flag may have gotten set at some point, and it would explain why a simplified program no longer showed this behaviour.

Comment: Crazy, I thought that there must have been some flags register that should control this behavior. Thanks a lot!