# Can the result of bitwise SIMD logical operations on packed floating points be corrupted by FTZ/DAZ or -ffinite-math-only?

Tags: floating-point, x86-64, cpu-architecture, simd, sse

Recall that the exponent mask for a 32 bit float is `0x7F80'0000`, and a number is a denormal if and only if that mask consists of all zeroes, and there's at least one non-zero bit in the mantissa; similarly, if the exponent part of a float consists of only ones,  the value is either an INF (mantissa of all zeroes), or a NaN (mantissa with some non-zero bits).

FTZ (flush-to-zero) and DAZ (denormals-are-zero) are two register flags that, if set, change the behavior of the CPU (so they're a runtime thing, the same binary code will behave differently depending on these flags). The first one will truncate to zero denormal values resulting from (certain?) operations on floating points, whereas the second ensures that any denormal value encountered by the CPU during (certain?) operations is treated as zero. I couldn't find any documentation on which operations are affected by these flags, so if you know any, I would really appreciate the reference.

On a different part of the spectrum, the flag `-ffinite-math-only` (one of the flags enabled by `-ffast-math` on GCC and Clang; similar considerations apply for `/fp:fast` on MSVC) enables codegen optimizations that are correct only assuming all floating points encountered in code are NOT INFs or NaNs.

Given all that, these are my questions:

- can a (e.g.) `0x0000'FFFF` returned by a call to `_mm_cmpeq_ps()` be flushed to zero (possibly only on some micro-architectures)? (I'm aware that the actual comparison IS affected by DAZ, as any denormal will compare equal to zero, as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54047888, so that's not what I'm asking; but this very fact is what worries me when it comes to bitwise logical operations)
- can a mask like `0x0000'FFFF` be treated as zero when used (e.g.) as an argument for `_mm_and_ps()`?
- can the compiler do optimizations that will invalidate the correctness of the generated code on masks like `0xFFFF'0000`, since strictly speaking they're NaNs?

If these are actual issues, one possible workaround (at least for bitwise logical operations) would be using the integer counterparts of the relevant instructions, but that might incur in delays due to different execution domains, depending on the CPU microarchitecture. Moreover, for comparison instructions, it would just not work as-is, and one would have to write auxiliary methods to basically re-implement IEEE-754's comparisons, which is less than ideal. I'm hoping that both the register and the compiler flags have been implemented with the background assumption that they'll "do the right thing", but I couldn't find any information about this.

Comment: It would be quite absurd if floating-point flags affected integer operations.  So I'm sure the answer is no, but it may be hard to find it stated explicitly, just because documentation authors would probably consider it obvious.  You might find somewhere a clause that flags like DAZ affect floating-point instructions only.

Comment: @NateEldredge the problem is that the actual SSE instructions mentioned aren't integer operations, at the assembly level. Take the AND instruction, for example, `andps` and `pand` have different opcodes. Same thing for `cmpps` and `pcmpeqq`. Depending on the microarchitecture, they might actually be physically processed in different units of the CPU.

Comment: Regarding hardware instructions: The instructions that return bit masks do not flush to zero. Regarding compiler treatment of NaN/infinity patterns: The SIMD intrinsics for instructions returning masks have return types that are either generic vectors or integer vectors, and the compiler should not assume they do not have NaN or infinity patterns because it should not assume they contain floating-point data as long as you do not perform operations that treat them as floating-point (such as taking an element out of them and using it in floating-point operations).

Comment: `andps` and `pand` are architecturally identical, to the very best of my knowledge, and the same for the other bitwise instructions.  There is a potential microarchitectural difference, for avoiding domain forwarding penalties, which may affect performance but not architectural behavior.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804902/whats-the-difference-between-logical-sse-intrinsics/31233017#31233017, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62111946/what-is-the-point-of-sse2-instructions-such-as-orpd, ...

Comment: ..., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996384/do-i-get-a-performance-penalty-when-mixing-sse-integer-float-simd-instructions/4998071#4998071, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39811577/does-using-mix-of-pxor-and-xorps-affect-performance, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26942952/difference-between-the-avx-instructions-vxorpd-and-vpxor, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69095326/why-does-clang-emit-a-32-bit-float-ps-instruction-for-the-absolute-value-of-a-64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can a (e.g.) `0x0000'FFFF` returned by a call to `_mm_cmpeq_ps()` be flushed to zero (possibly only on some micro-architectures)?

`_mm_cmpeq_ps()` returns all-ones or all-zeros in each 32-bit element of a vector, so either 0xFFFFFFFF or 0. You may get a 0x0000FFFF from an integer instruction, such as `_mm_cmpeq_epi16`.

Whether the value is interpreted as zero depends on the instruction that receives such a value on input. Basically, DAZ and FTZ only apply to instructions that need to interpret the FP values in vectors. For example, if you pass it to an `addps` (`_mm_add_ps`) as an input argument then yes, that value may be interpreted as zero, depending on the DAZ flag in MXCSR. If you pass it to a bitwise operation such as `andps` or store it to memory then no, the value is used unchanged.

> can a mask like `0x0000'FFFF` be treated as zero when used (e.g.) as an argument for `_mm_and_ps()`?

No, bitwise operations have equivalent effect between integer and FP domains; `andps` and `andpd` work exactly like `pand`. Similarly, various shuffle instructions like `unpcklps` and `shufps` don't interpret the FP values and operate on bits "as is".

> can the compiler do optimizations that will invalidate the correctness of the generated code on masks like `0xFFFF'0000`, since strictly speaking they're NaNs?

You will have to ask your compiler vendor or look into its code. Formally, I don't think the compiler is prohibited to perform optimizations on the code assuming that there will be no NaNs or infinities.

In practice, in vectorized code compilers usually don't interpret vector contents too deeply, especially if they originate from memory that is initialized elsewhere, which is a typical use case for vector code. Bit patterns that correspond to NaNs and infinity may appear in vectors as a result of bitwise operations or loads from memory, and those patterns are not prohibited by `-ffast-math`. This means that the compiler needs to generate vector code that is more-or-less ambivalent to the input data and fairly corresponds to what the programmer wrote. But the compiler may still perform optimizations on the vectorized code that can affect the result of computations (for example, convert a pair of `mulps` and `addps` to an FMA equivalent).

Flags like `-ffast-math` mostly apply to scalar operations, where the FP values are more predictable and operations often involve standard library calls like `isnan`. These library calls, as well as any code that depend on their result, can be outright eliminated as a result of `-ffast-math`.

If your code has a vectorized section that passes its results to a scalar section, you should be careful if the vectorized part can produce special FP values. If you enable `-ffast-math` and the scalar code attempts to handle special values from the vector code, you may find that that handling doesn't work. In that case, either handle the special values in the vector code before exposing those to the scalar code, or disable `-ffast-math`, at least locally, where that special value handling is done.

Comment: A good rule of thumb for whether FTZ/DAZ can affect an instruction is to look at whether it can raise any FP math exceptions; yes for `addps` / `mulps`, no for `movaps` / `orps` etc.  e.g. [`maxps`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/maxps#simd-floating-point-exceptions) can raise Invalid and/or Denormal.  It doesn't have to round its output so might do FTZ, but does have to process its input like a compare.  [`roundps`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/roundps) can raise some, and even mentions that DAZ affects whether a Denormal exception is raised. (It already rounds to integer so not FTZ.)